# How to pass a completion block to another class in Swift

Tags: swift, block

In Objective-C, I used this handling of a completion-block that now must be transformed to Swift:

in **DetailDisplayController.h**

```
typedef void (^AddedCompletitionBlock)(BOOL saved, NSString *primarykey, NSUInteger recordCount);

@interface DetailDisplayController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) AddedCompletitionBlock completionBlock;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Details *detail;
```

in **DetailDisplayController.m**

```
- (void) saveClicked:(id)sender
{  
   // retrieve PK
   NSString *objectId = [[[_detail objectID] URIRepresentation] absoluteString];

   if (self.completionBlock != nil)
   {
       self.completionBlock(_rowChanged, objectId, [_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]);
   }
```

_rowChanged and _fetchedResultsController are instance-variables

and in **DetailViewController.m** a the calling class, the passed block is used

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailDisplay"])
   {
       DetailDisplayController *detailDisplayController = segue.destinationViewController; 
       ...
       detailDisplayController.completionBlock = ^(BOOL saved, NSString *sorter, NSUInteger recordCount)
       {
        if (saved)
           ...
```

How can I do this in Swift?

Comment: Functions in Swift can be passed like variables.

Comment: Ok, i can pass a function from the calling class. But how to share the variables in the called class?

Comment: Please show what you are trying to do and an attempt at a solution (in Swift).

Comment: sorry shim, there is nothing to show cause i dont´t know how to start :-( I´m just googling for  an solution. Meanwhile i think, my Swift-knowledge is too poor to resolve this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the equivalent pieces that you need in Swift:

```
typealias AddedCompletionBlock = (saved: Bool, primaryKey: String, recordCount: Int) -> Void

var completionBlock: AddedCompletionBlock? = nil

completionBlock = {saved, primaryKey, recordCount in
    print("\(saved), \(primaryKey), \(recordCount)")
}

completionBlock?(saved: true, primaryKey: "key", recordCount: 1)
```

You probably want to have a good read of the ["Function Types"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID174) and ["Closures"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) sections of the Apple Swift docs.

Comment: Hi Ewan, many THX, that´s it. I only had to move the line "completionBlock = {saved, primaryKey, recordCount in" to my DetailViewController.m...
And i dont have to read anything, i understood it all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift completions are really easy. Here is an example. I press the button to open a SecondVC and then I press a button on the SecondVC to close it and I call a completion which is going to change a label on the FirstVC:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        vc.completion = { str in
            self.label.text = str
        }
    }
 }
```

and this is what the SecondVC looks like:

```
 class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    var completion:((String)->())?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        completion?("Hello")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```